# Mostrar por consola una imagen en Python con PIL Image

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda

Estoy haciendo un trabajo en Jupyter notebook con Anaconda y quiero mostrar una imagen que previamente he descargado.

```
img = urllib.request.urlopen(peliA["Poster"]).read()
                manf3 = open("posters/"+peliA["imdbID"]+".jpg", "wb") #guardamos poster con el nombre del ID de pelicula
manf3.write(img)
manf3.close
```

Con ese código la descarga se realiza correctamente.

Luego quiero mostrarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
imagen = Image.open("posters/"+peliA["imdbID"]+".jpg")
imagen.show()
```

Previamente he incluido `from PIL import Image` pero la imagen se me muestra con el visor de imagenes de Windows y yo quiero que se muestre en la misma consola de Jupyter

Buscando he encontrado gente que ponía simplemente  `Image.open(filename="posters/"+peliA["imdbID"]+".jpg")` y les funcionaba pero a mi me da el error `'module' object is not callable`

¿Alguien sabe como podría mostrarlo en consola y no con el visor por defecto de Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un notebook Jupyter tiene capacidad de mostrar diferentes tipos de objetos Python automáticamente, sin más que volcarlos desde una celda.

Si por ejemplo, en una celda pones el siguiente código para cargar una imagen:

```
img = Image.open("imagen.jpg")
```

En otra puedes poner simplemente `img` para inspeccionar esa variable, y te mostrará la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad lo que ocurre es que Jupyter usa un método interno llamado `display()` para mostrar el contenido de la variable. Ese método decide "inteligentemente" cómo mostrar el objeto según el frontend usado. Cuando el objeto es una imagen y el frontend es un navegador directamente le envía la imagen en forma de elemento `<img>` para que el navegador pueda mostrarla.

Si quieres puedes importar tú mismo el método `display()` para usarlo, así:

```
from IPython.display import display
display(img)
```

y tendrías el mismo resultado que el que mostré en la anterior captura de pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

El módulo PIL (pillow) es un módulo que se utiliza más que todo en el diseño de las interfaces gráficas
No puede mostrar imágenes en una ventana de consola. Necesita un conjunto de herramientas gráficas como Tkinter, según su código usted
está mostrando la imagen desde su visor de imágenes predeterminado algo que es lógico y que usted si puede hacer, como lo mencione antes la consola no puede mostrar elementos gráficos como imágenes u otro elemento gráfico visual.

Comment: El usuario ha especificado que trabaja con un Jupyter Notebook. Este framework sí que tiene capacidad de mostrar imágenes. No se refiere a una consola "terminal de windows".

Comment: Gracias por su comentario, no tenía en cuenta esa posible solución, aunque el titulo de la pregunta dice consola en general, de igual forma le agradezco por el comentario, no tenía en cuenta eso.